# Why can't I open or load USB device with GUID or VID / PID

Tags: c#, usb, rfid, libusbdotnet

I would like to read the contents of an RFID card via a USB reader.

I installed the Nuget package: LibUsbDotNet

I get the guid, pid, vid via the Windows Device Manager :-

> L'appareil USB\VID_1667&PID_0005\PGM-T1048 a été configuré.

> GUID de classe : {36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}

I'm trying:

```
    UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinderTest = new UsbDeviceFinder(new Guid("36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000"));
    
    //or
    
    UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinderTest = new UsbDeviceFinder(1667, 5);
    
    //or
    
    int vid = Int32.Parse("1667", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    int pid = Int32.Parse("0005", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    
    UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinderTest = new UsbDeviceFinder(vid, pid);
    
    UsbDevice MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinderTest);
```

But MyUsbFinderTest always returns null.

Can you help me?

Comment: How about using it like this sample, for example? [LibUsbDotNet/src/Examples/Read.Write/ReadWrite.cs](https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet/blob/master/src/Examples/Read.Write/ReadWrite.cs)

Comment: Thx but same thing if I connect using the UsbContext

Comment: Looking at this, it seems to be keyboard emulation, so you may not need a library. [USB\VID_1667&PID_0005](https://www.devicekb.com/en/usb-vendors/vid_1667-pid_0005)

Comment: How can I do then? winscard

Comment: for info: Périphérique USB composite USB\VID_1667&PID_0005\PGM-T1048 PID=5 VID=5735 ==> result ==> Select * From Win32_USBHub

Comment: Isn't the data notified as a key press when the RFID is placed near the reader? Or is there anything in the user manual or materials like the SDK?

Comment: Isn't the data notified as a key press when the RFID is placed near the reader ==> YES No Manual ==> Code de produit: PCR300FMU-00

Comment: Probably this device, so ask your vendor how to use it. [Proximity EM RFID Reader \125KHz EM Card Reader](http://www.gigatms.com.tw/products-detail1.asp?pid=151), [PCR330 USB RFID Reader](https://dustinweb.azureedge.net/media/240734/rfid-reader-pcr-330m-usb.pdf)

Comment: ==> 8F.,NO.31, LANE 169, KANG-NING
STREET,HSI-CHIH,TAIPEI,TAIWAN  ...... and can i use winscard.dll ?

Comment: I'm just guessing from the results of the search based on the keywords in the article, so I don't know the details. Please ask the vendor or a user who has experience using the same device.

Comment: I think it must be possible with winscard.dll, I still sent an email to the supplier but do not think I have a return thank you for your time