# Can't read RFID card USB with winscard.dll c#

Tags: c#, rfid, smartcard-reader, winscard

I'have reader: Promag PCR-300FMU, USB (no manuel, no SDK).

[image]

So I looked after the doc on winscard.dll

```
public List<string> ListReaders()
    {
        int ReaderCount = 0;
        List<string> AvailableReaderList = new List<string>();

        //Make sure a context has been established before 
        //retrieving the list of smartcard readers.
        retCode = Card.SCardListReaders(hContext, null, null, ref ReaderCount);
        if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Card.GetScardErrMsg(retCode));
            //connActive = false;
        }

        byte[] ReadersList = new byte[ReaderCount];

        //Get the list of reader present again but this time add sReaderGroup, retData as 2rd & 3rd parameter respectively.
        retCode = Card.SCardListReaders(hContext, null, ReadersList, ref ReaderCount);
        if (retCode != Card.SCARD_S_SUCCESS)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Card.GetScardErrMsg(retCode));
        }

        string rName = "";
        int indx = 0;
        if (ReaderCount > 0)
        {
            // Convert reader buffer to string
            while (ReadersList[indx] != 0)
            {

                while (ReadersList[indx] != 0)
                {
                    rName = rName + (char)ReadersList[indx];
                    indx = indx + 1;
                }

                //Add reader name to list
                AvailableReaderList.Add(rName);
                rName = "";
                indx = indx + 1;

            }
        }
        return AvailableReaderList;

    }
```

this.ListReaders() send me back ==> one item ==> Generic EMV Smartcard Reader 0 ==> this is not my reader

Here are the VIDs and PIDs that I get

USB\VID_1667&PID_0005&MI_01\6&DE89751&0&0001
VID: 1667
PID: 0005
USB\VID_1667&PID_0005&MI_00\6&DE89751&0&0000
VID: 1667
PID: 0005
USB\VID_1667&PID_0005\PGM-T1048
VID: 1667
PID: 0005

```
        public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice1;
    public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder1 = new UsbDeviceFinder(1667, 0005);
    public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice2;
    public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder2 = new UsbDeviceFinder(Int32.Parse("1667", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber), Int32.Parse("0005", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //GetAllVidAndPidOnPC();
        MyUsbDevice1 = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder1);
        MyUsbDevice2 = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder2);

    }
```

Always NULL in MyUsbDevice1 a MyUsbDevice2

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Your reader is not a smartcard reader. You can't use it through winscard.

You can read it using the [LibUsbDotNet](https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet) library for example and code it this way :

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;

namespace Examples
{
internal class ReadPolling
{
    public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice;

    #region SET YOUR USB Vendor and Product ID!

    public static UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(1234, 1);

    #endregion

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ErrorCode ec = ErrorCode.None;

        try
        {
            // Find and open the usb device.
            MyUsbDevice = UsbDevice.OpenUsbDevice(MyUsbFinder);

            // If the device is open and ready
            if (MyUsbDevice == null) throw new Exception("Device Not Found.");

            // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb-1.0)
            // it exposes an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the 
            // 'wholeUsbDevice' variable will be null indicating this is 
            // an interface of a device; it does not require or support 
            // configuration and interface selection.
            IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
            if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
            {
                // This is a "whole" USB device. Before it can be used, 
                // the desired configuration and interface must be selected.

                // Select config #1
                wholeUsbDevice.SetConfiguration(1);

                // Claim interface #0.
                wholeUsbDevice.ClaimInterface(0);
            }

            // open read endpoint 1.
            UsbEndpointReader reader = MyUsbDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep01);


            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            while (ec == ErrorCode.None)
            {
                int bytesRead;

                // If the device hasn't sent data in the last 5 seconds,
                // a timeout error (ec = IoTimedOut) will occur. 
                ec = reader.Read(readBuffer, 5000, out bytesRead);

                if (bytesRead == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("{0}:No more bytes!", ec));
                Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes read", bytesRead);

                // Write that output to the console.
                Console.Write(Encoding.Default.GetString(readBuffer, 0, bytesRead));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\r\nDone!\r\n");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine((ec != ErrorCode.None ? ec + ":" : String.Empty) + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (MyUsbDevice != null)
            {
                if (MyUsbDevice.IsOpen)
                {
                    // If this is a "whole" usb device (libusb-win32, linux libusb-1.0)
                    // it exposes an IUsbDevice interface. If not (WinUSB) the 
                    // 'wholeUsbDevice' variable will be null indicating this is 
                    // an interface of a device; it does not require or support 
                    // configuration and interface selection.
                    IUsbDevice wholeUsbDevice = MyUsbDevice as IUsbDevice;
                    if (!ReferenceEquals(wholeUsbDevice, null))
                    {
                        // Release interface #0.
                        wholeUsbDevice.ReleaseInterface(0);
                    }

                    MyUsbDevice.Close();
                }
                MyUsbDevice = null;

                // Free usb resources
                UsbDevice.Exit();

            }

            // Wait for user input..
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response but I have already tried and still get a null in the object: MyUsbDevice ==> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65242520/why-cant-i-open-or-load-usb-device-with-guid-or-vid-pid?noredirect=1#comment115381813_65242520

Comment: I try: UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinderTest = new UsbDeviceFinder(new Guid("36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000")); or UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinderTest = new UsbDeviceFinder(1667, 5); or UsbDeviceFinder MyUsbFinderTest = new UsbDeviceFinder(5735, 5); I have always a null with méthode: OpenUsbDevice

Comment: It's work ! I'have install but IoTimedOut:IoTimedOut:No more bytes!

Comment: Nice ! If everything is working from now, could you please validate/improve the solution please ?

Comment: I just install the https://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/ but I can't read what is on the card ==> if (bytesRead == 0) throw new Exception(string.Format("{0}:No more bytes!", ec)); WHY ?

Comment: It is an example code, you can modify it of course.
And if bytesRead = 0 it because when you're calling the reader.Read() method, there is no data sent from your USB device.